# How to prove that a $f(x)=x^2$ is a Borel function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

How to prove that a $f(x)=x^2$ is a Borel function?

I don't know how to do this type of prove. I find the the measure theory very abstract and have some problems with grasping the concepts (especially sigma algebra, Borel sigma algebra and topics related to this). 
Could anybody explain please ?

Comment: So what is your definition of "Borel function"? It should have something to do with $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O})$ for open sets $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Showing that $f$ is continuous would suffice.

Comment: function which is Borel measurable -> function that the inverse image of any open set in its codomain is a Borel set of its domian. That's the definition but I don't quite get it.

Comment: Do you want a proof using only the defintion of Borel function?

Comment: @sinbadh possibly yes, so that I could grasp the concept and be able to apply to other functions

Comment: Is every continuous function Borel-measurable? (If you already know that this is true, then you're basically done. If you don't, well, it's true — why?)

Comment: @BrianO Suppose you have a topology space $(X,\tau)$ and a continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, where the last has the usual topology. If you take the measurable space $(X,\sigma(\tau))$, then $f$ is Borel-measurable.

Comment: @sinbadh Consider this forwarded to the OP ;) whom I was asking. (I know the answer :) While correct, your reply might be a little too abstract for OP.